# Firebase observeSingleEvent completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a FirebaseManager class and a get data function.
When calling this function, I need to get this data in the place from which it is called.
I am trying to do something like

```
import Firebase

class FirebaseManager {
    
    var ref = Database.database().reference()
 
    func getData (path: String) -> DataSnapshot {
        
        self.ref.child(path).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                print(snapshot.value!)
        return snapshot // XCODE ERROR - Cannot convert return expression of type 'Void' to return type 'DataSnapshot'
            } else {
                print("No data by path \(path)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your title suggests, what you'll need a completion handler. You can pass that in as a parameter to your function. It might look something like this:

```
func getData(path: String, completion: @escaping (DataSnapshot) -> Void) {
    self.ref.child(path).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            completion(snapshot)
        } else {
            print("No data by path \(path)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
getData(path: "myPath") { snapshot in
  //do something with snapshot here
}
//no access to snapshot here
```

Note that you have access to `snapshot` *inside* the closure (the `{ }`), so you can't access snapshot *after* the closure.

Personally, I'd probably refactor a bit so that you'd be returning the actual data than you want from inside the snapshot (like a `String`, a `Dictionary`, etc) rather than returning the `DataSnapshot` itself, but that's a matter of preference.

Comment: thnx a lot, friend!

Comment: Glad it helped. You can mark the answer as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark.